# How to use a view's reference in xml to pass arguments to a function using data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

I am using data binding to call a function of my viewmodel but the function requires the values of the edittext. But I don't know how to pass the value of other views.

Here is the xml code. In this I want to pass the value of password edittext to viewmodel on click of the button. 
Suggest me a way to do this other than using onclickListeners in fragment and calling the function from there.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/big_action_button_red"
            android:text="@string/login_button_text"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.validateUser(password_input.text)}"/>
```

Comment: Just you want validate `password` field in `validateUser` method it that you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Two-way data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) with the password `TextView`, that way you can have the current value of the field in a `LiveData` in your `ViewModel`.
Then simply get that value inside your `ViewModel` when `validate()` is called.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@={viewmodel.passowrd}"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create string variable in your `viewmodel` for password field like this

```
  var password:String?=null
```

Now add this in `password_input` field just like this

```
 android:text="@={viewmodel.password}" // this directly assign value of password field to password variable
```

Now at last remove parameter in `validateUser` method and directly use `password` variable in this method.

Comment: Using the variable type as String? gives an error but works fine when MutableLiveData is used instead.